# Looking for a recipe generator

Tags: websites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one find recipes given an ingredient rather than the recipe name?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-does-one-find-recipes-given-an-ingredient-rather-than-the-recipe-name)

I'd like to get a recipe by given food (fridge content ;) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After years of cooking, I don't really need this service anymore, but I sure did wish there was something good like this 5 years ago. I couldn't find anything then, though. However, I've seen a couple of sites pop up since then. I can't really testify to how well they work, because I haven't used any of them. But here are some things to explore:

[Recipe Key](http://www.recipekey.com) - Lets you create your own pantry and then get matching recipes. This looks like it could be a really cool tool if you use it regularly as well as a good spot solution for inspiration.

[Recipe Matcher](http://www.recipematcher.com) - Lets you type in the ingredients you have for matches.

And now I need to run, so here are a couple more sites to check out:

- [Super Cook](http://www.supercook.com)
- [All Recipes](http://allrecipes.com/search/ingredients.aspx)
- [Recipe Puppy](http://www.recipepuppy.com)
- [Yummly](http://www.yummly.com)

Hope one of those helps. I think the first two (recipe key and recipe matcher) look like your best options. Let us know how you fare.

Comment: Thank you! I will try them next time. I'm marking this question as answered now. However, other people still can provide their favorite pages.

Answer (score 1):

@yossarian provides excellent links, and I would like to add that typing the ingredients into Google is a good starting point.