# What can I bake with only flour, water and sugar?

Tags: bread

This won't be haute cuisine unfortunately, but I am kind of stuck. I want to bake some snacks, but have only access to water, flour and sugar (student, between two jobs, need to save). I'm pretty sure I can make something "edible" out of it, that I could then dip into peanut butter, jelly, or whatever I have laying around here.

The only requirements are:

- need to use only water, flour, and sugar/salt (no baking powder, or eggs)
- edible (crackers-like things are ok, but no rock-like things)
- doesn't have to taste great, or even to have a taste at all

So, what is your most simple and minimalist recipe available?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but we don't accept recipe requests or questions of the form "what should I make/eat" here. This is an even more open-ended form of recipe requests where people are free to post anything at all using those (extremely common) ingredients. Might I suggest one of the many [ingredient-based recipe searches](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12736/41)?

Comment: Well, the idea was to know what I could bake using ONLY these ingredients, nothing added. Every ingredient-based recipe search I found only allows me to select a few ingredients I don't want, whereas what I don't want is "everything else". And so, I find myself with thousands of recipes, exactly because the ingredients are too common. I will try the suggestions below.

Comment: Those really aren't the only cheap ingredients.

Comment: No, but they are the only ones I have availaible, and I don't have the possibility of buying more. I ended up making sacramental bread by the way.

Answer (score 3):

With flour, water, and salt you could make sourdough bread. The idea is to encourage wild yeast to grow in a mix of flour and water, which you then use to leaven your bread. It will take a few days to get a culture/starter going in the first place, but once you've done so you can use it to raise all sorts of breads.

Answer (score 3):

You can make Indian flatbreads such as [roti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roti) and [chapati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapati). They're great with savory stuff, but they will go well with peanut butter and jam too!