# What to do with leftover egg whites?

Tags: culinary-uses, egg-whites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one find recipes given an ingredient rather than the recipe name?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-does-one-find-recipes-given-an-ingredient-rather-than-the-recipe-name)

I am a beginner cooker.

I have just cooked Carbonara Pasta, and I'm left with three or four egg whites.

Instead of throwing them out, what can be made with them?

Comment: Meringue or fried egg.

Comment: Everytime I'm left with egg whites and I'm wondering what to do with them, I make meringue. Then I wonder what to do with the meringue.

Comment: maybe you could ask the question, "what meals could be accompanied with meringue ?"... maybe there are salted flavours that would match very well. Maybe ;-)

Comment: @citizen: crumble them and use them to cover cakes! :)

Comment: This is a very open-ended question and not a great fit for a Q&A site. Please refer to our [culinary uses guidelines](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/740/41) and the linked recipe search question. There is certainly no shortage of egg-white recipes on any of those recipe-search sites; pick one that looks easy.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like an Angel Food cake. I'm not a fan of Angel Food so I would save and probably scramble them with some cheese and tomatoes (or whatever you like and have handy) the next day for breakfast. Another option is to make the Carbonara using whole eggs, no leftover whites to deal with then.

Comment: Then you'd have scrambled egg carbonara...

Answer (score 3):

You can freeze egg whites and use them later.

You can make meringue cookies. Or Pavlova.

You can spread egg white on a pie, to give it a nice, glossy coat.