# Uses for cheap beer?

Tags: beer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one find recipes given an ingredient rather than the recipe name?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-does-one-find-recipes-given-an-ingredient-rather-than-the-recipe-name)

I have found myself saddled with a preponderance of cheap beer that I have no interest in drinking, but I don't wan to let it go to waste.  What else can I do with it?

Comment: Beer does not line up with our [culinary uses guidelines](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/740/41). Please see the linked dupe to do a recipe search - any search engine will come up with hundreds of recipes.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for the heads-up and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I was once on a road trip, and we traded 2 cases of beer for time on someone's welder so we could fix the leak from a crack in one of the trailer's rims.  Does that count?

Comment: And having grown up as a military brat ... the standard practice that I learned was 2 beers for each person that you'd actually want to drink, and then the rest was whatever was cheapest.  After the first two, you really don't notice the quality of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Use it for baking crêpes, pancakes.
Just eggs and flour, then mix in the beer till the batter is thin, a pinch of salt and bake them in a very hot pan, using a drop of oil.

Comment: This question was closed as there's already a [question on finding recipes given an ingredient](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12736/14096).